# After installing MVC3, I can't create or open projects for MVC2 on visual studio 2010

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

Opening MVC2 Projects just makes "project not supported" error on visual studio, and i can't find the template for creating new projects for mvc2.

I undertand that the mvc2 new project template could be not desired after installing mvc3, but the support for editing and maitaining mvc2 projects should still be there.

in the release notes it states:

> ASP.NET MVC 3 can be installed side by
>   side with ASP.NET MVC 2 on the same
>   computer, which gives you flexibility
>   in choosing when to upgrade an ASP.NET
>   MVC 2 application to ASP.NET MVC 3

I know I have mvc1, mvc2 and mvc3 dlls "side by side" on my GAC, but i'm still hoping this visual studio error is a error in my setup.

If not, ¿Is possible to upgrade the project file and keep all contents the same, pointing to the mvc2 dll?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer my own question after a few attempts:

Yes, it is possible to upgrade the project without altering MVC2. Just apply step 8 of the manual migration procedure on the release notes for MVC3:

> 8-    Locate the ProjectTypeGuids element and replace
>   {F85E285D-A4E0-4152-9332-AB1D724D3325}
>   with
>   {E53F8FEA-EAE0-44A6-8774-FFD645390401}.

and reload the project.

This should be all.

The downside is that if other people are working on this project, they will now need to install MVC3 too, in order to get Visual Studio to recognize this new project GUID.